hadoop HA with qjm wrong installation
this is my first installation of Hadoop HA with qjs and I'm having a lot of troubles from at least one whole week.
The lab is setup as follow
10.0.0.10 zoo1 solr1 had1
10.0.0.11 zoo2 solr2 had2
10.0.0.12 zoo3 solr3 had3
10.0.0.15            had4

*.10, *.11, *.12 are the zookeeper cluster
*.10 and *.15 work as hadoop leader namenodes , while *.11 and *.12 are the datanodes
*.10, *.11, *.12 are the solr cluster
zookeeper and solr clusters work fine together but when I tried to set up hadoop to put the solr indexes on,
everything went wrong
please find atttached the recipe I wrote and the logs I got, ANY help will be truly appreciated and if you'll come along in Italy I'll surely offer a dinner :)
###############################
RECIPE
###############################
### all  vms
ID=hadoop
useradd -m -d /home/$ID -s /bin/bash $ID -k /etc/skel/
chown $ID:$ID -R /home/$ID
usermod -aG installers hadoop

echo "$ID:D1x2j13%%2nk4" | chpasswd
mkdir -p /data/hadoop/hdfs/namenode /data/hadoop/hdfs/datanode
chown root /data/
chgrp installers /data/
chmod g+rw /data/
chown hadoop:hadoop /data/hadoop -R
echo 'DATA_DIR=/data/hadoop' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
sudo -u hadoop echo '45=+FG76%&df@' > /home/hadoop/http-signature.secret

### namenodes

cd /opt/
HADOOP=hadoop-3.4.0.tar.gz
curl -O https://dlcdn.apache.org/hadoop/common/hadoop-3.4.0/$HADOOP
tar xvzf $HADOOP
ln -sf ./hadoop-3.4.0 ./hadoop
chown -R hadoop:hadoop /opt/hadoop /opt/hadoop-3.4.0 /data/hadoop $HADOOP
su - $ID
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
ssh-keygen -t rsa
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
DATA_DIR=/data/hadoop
DIRS='data,name,pid,tmp,yarn-local_dir,journal/node/local/data'

for IP in 10.0.0.{11..12} ; do ssh-copy-id  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub $IP; scp -r ./.ssh/id_rs* $IP:/home/hadoop/.ssh/; chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys ; done
for IP in 10.0.0.{11..12} ; do scp -r /opt/$HADOOP $IP:/opt/ && ssh $IP "cd /opt/ && tar xvzf $HADOOP && ln -sf ./hadoop-3.4.0 ./hadoop" ; done
for IP in 10.0.0.{10..12} ; do ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new $IP "mkdir -p $DATA_DIR/{$DIRS}" ; done

echo -e "export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/javac | sed "s:bin/javac::")" > /etc/profile.d/hadoop

cat > /opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop/workers << EOF
had3
had4
EOF

--> both users  root and hadoop

echo -e 'export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/javac | sed "s:bin/javac::")
export PDSH_RCMD_TYPE=ssh
export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HDFS_NAMENODE_USER="hadoop"
export HDFS_DATANODE_USER="hadoop"
export HDFS_SECONDARYNAMENODE_USER="hadoop"
export HDFS_JOURNALNODE_USER="hadoop"
export YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_USER="hadoop"
export YARN_NODEMANAGER_USER="hadoop"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin' >> ~/.bashrc

echo -e 'export HADOOP_OS_TYPE=${HADOOP_OS_TYPE:-$(uname -s)}
export HADOOP_PID_DIR=/data/hadoop/pid
export HDFS_DATANODE_OPTS="-Dhadoop.security.logger=ERROR,RFAS"
export HDFS_DATANODE_USER=hadoop
export HDFS_NAMENODE_OPTS="-Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,RFAS"
export HDFS_NAMENODE_USER=hadoop
export HDFS_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS="-Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,RFAS"
export HDFS_SECONDARYNAMENODE_USER=hadoop
export HDFS_JOURNALNODE_USER=hadoop
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export YARN_NODEMANAGER_OPTS="$YARN_NODEMANAGER_OPTS -Djava.security.manager=allow -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED"
export YARN_NODEMANAGER_USER=hadoop
export YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_OPTS="$YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_OPTS -Djava.security.manager=allow -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED"
export YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_USER=hadoop' > /opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh

cat > /opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml << EOF
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://innen</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/data/hadoop/tmp/</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>io.file.buffer.size</name>
    <value>131072</value>
  </property>
<property>
    <name>hadoop.http.authentication.signature.secret.file</name>
    <value>/home/hadoop/http-signature.secret</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>ha.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>had1:2181,had2:2181,had3:2181</value>
</property>
</configuration>
EOF

cat > /opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml << EOF
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>3</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>file:///data/hadoop/hdfs/namenode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>file:///data/hadoop/hdfs/datanode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>ha.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>had1:2181,had2:2181,had3:2181</value>
    </property>
<!-- start cluster section -->
    <!-- definisco nome cluster e namenodes -->
        <property>
            <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
            <value>innen</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>dfs.ha.namenodes.innen</name>
            <value>had1,had4</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.innen.had1</name>
            <value>had1:8020</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.innen.had4</name>
            <value>had4:8020</value>
        </property>
    <!-- definisco namenode fqdn -->
        <property>
            <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.innen.had1</name>
            <value>had1:9870</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.innen.had4</name>
            <value>had4:9870</value>
        </property>
    <!-- URI del gruppo di journalnodes dove i namenodes +rw i log -->
        <property>
            <name>dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir</name>
            <value>qjournal://had1:8485;had4:8485/innen</value>
        </property>
    <!-- determina il failover -->
        <property>
            <name>dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.innen</name>
            <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider</value>
        </property>
    <!-- definisce il fencing, sdraia tutto via ssh -->
        <property>
            <name>dfs.ha.fencing.methods</name>
            <value>sshfence</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>dfs.ha.fencing.ssh.private-key-files</name>
            <value>/home/hadoop/.ssh/id_rsa</value>
        </property>
    <!-- path assoluta dove i jn scrivono -->
        <property>
            <name>dfs.journalnode.edits.dir</name>
            <value>/data/hadoop/journal/node/local/data</value>
        </property>
<!-- end cluster section -->
</configuration>
EOF

echo -e 'export YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_OPTS="$YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_OPTS -Djava.security.manager=allow -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED"
export YARN_NODEMANAGER_OPTS="$YARN_NODEMANAGER_OPTS -Djava.security.manager=allow -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED"' >> /opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop/yarn-env.sh

cat > /opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml << EOF
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>had1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.min-healthy-disks</name>
        <value>0</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
        <value>/data/hadoop/yarn-local_dir</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
EOF

### on the  journalnodes

hdfs --daemon start journalnode

### sul node main master

/opt/hadoop/bin/hdfs namenode -format  <-- just once

        --> $HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-all.sh <--

###############################################

one of the errors I get is
java.net.ConnectException: Call From controlplane/127.0.2.1 to had4:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:948)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:863)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1588)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1529)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1426)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:139)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy17.rollEditLog(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.NamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.lambda$rollEditLog$4(NamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.internal.ShadedProtobufHelper.ipc(ShadedProtobufHelper.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.NamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.rollEditLog(NamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer$2.doWork(EditLogTailer.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer$2.doWork(EditLogTailer.java:414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer$MultipleNameNodeProxy.call(EditLogTailer.java:598)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:668)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:789)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$3800(Client.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1649)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1473)
    ... 14 more
2024-08-09 14:10:01,808 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer: Have reached the max loop count (3).
2024-08-09 14:10:01,808 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer: Unable to trigger a roll of the active NN
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Cannot find any valid remote NN to service request!
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer.triggerActiveLogRoll(EditLogTailer.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer$EditLogTailerThread.doWork(EditLogTailer.java:511)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer$EditLogTailerThread.access$700(EditLogTailer.java:477)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer$EditLogTailerThread$1.run(EditLogTailer.java:494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.doAsLoginUserOrFatal(SecurityUtil.java:520)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer$EditLogTailerThread.run(EditLogTailer.java:490)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot find any valid remote NN to service request!
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer$MultipleNameNodeProxy.call(EditLogTailer.java:609)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

Actually the 8020 is open only on had1 but not on had4

and I get floods of these logs
2024-08-09 14:11:19,893 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: had4/10.0.0.15:8020. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2024-08-09 14:11:20,898 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: had4/10.0.0.15:8020. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2024-08-09 14:11:21,901 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: had4/10.0.0.15:8020. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2024-08-09 14:11:21,903 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer: Exception from remote name node RemoteNameNodeInfo [nnId=had4, ipcAddress=had4/10.0.0.15:8020, httpAddress=http://had4:9870], try next.
java.net.ConnectException: Call From controlplane/127.0.2.1 to had4:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

moreover if I try to list the fs with
hdfs dfs -ls /
I only get these errors
2024-08-09 14:12:16,117 INFO retry.RetryInvocationHandler: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException): Operation category READ is not supported in state standby. Visit https://s.apache.org/sbnn-error
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.StandbyState.checkOperation(StandbyState.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode$NameNodeHAContext.checkOperation(NameNode.java:2255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkOperation(FSNamesystem.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getFileInfo(FSNamesystem.java:3464)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getFileInfo(NameNodeRpcServer.java:1229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:1052)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:621)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:573)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:1246)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:1169)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:439)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1953)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:3203)
, while invoking ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo over had1/10.0.0.10:8020 after 2 failover attempts. Trying to failover after sleeping for 2639ms. Current retry count: 2.
2024-08-09 14:12:18,759 INFO retry.RetryInvocationHandler: java.net.ConnectException: Call From controlplane/127.0.2.1 to had4:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused, while invoking ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo over had4/10.0.0.15:8020 after 3 failover attempts. Trying to failover after sleeping for 3943ms. Current retry count: 3.
2024-08-09 14:12:22,706 INFO retry.RetryInvocationHandler: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException): Operation category READ is not supported in state standby. Visit https://s.apache.org/sbnn-error
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.StandbyState.checkOperation(StandbyState.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode$NameNodeHAContext.checkOperation(NameNode.java:2255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkOperation(FSNamesystem.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getFileInfo(FSNamesystem.java:3464)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getFileInfo(NameNodeRpcServer.java:1229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:1052)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:621)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:573)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:1246)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:1169)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:439)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1953)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:3203)
, while invoking ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo over had1/10.0.0.10:8020 after 4 failover attempts. Trying to failover after sleeping for 10146ms. Current retry count: 4.

I'm really out of ideas
Thanks in advance,
Sincerely
Roberto
The final goal is to create a 3 clusters with zookeeper managing hadoop and solr, which rw its indexes on hadoop mapreduced fs.
It has to be HA nad QJM is just a chance.

Connection refused usually indicates that the port isn't listening, or that the port has been firewalled away. Can you connect between the nodes with telnet <ip> 8020 to connect to the other port? Can you run nmap -a on .15 to see whether it's actually listening for connections on the correct interface? Since I'm seeing both local ips and hostnames, there might be issues with hostnames not resolving correctly or listening on one interface and trying to connect to an ip that is not being listened on.

maybe this could help someone else.
I solved the problem by my self, the point was the boot sequence.
In the documentation https://apache.github.io/hadoop/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html there  is written to format the fs for the image and then to start the namenode.
Unfortunately, setting up a cluster they forgot to mention that it need the journaling before the namenodes to run properly.
so this will be the recipe:
hdfs --daemon start journalnode
hdfs --daemon start namenode
hdfs --daemon start zkfc
sudo -u hadoop hdfs haadmin -transitionToActive <your_name_node> --forcemanual
hdfs --daemon start datanode
yarn --daemon start resourcemanager
yarn --daemon start nodemanager
yarn --daemon start proxyserver

